# Build index with white screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm looking to host a website developed with reactjs but when I generate the build and open the index the screen is white.

Comment: Look at the error console in your browser and see what the error is.

Comment: main.a2c5fc3c.chunk.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a server like apache or Nginx or other similar, opening the index file only will not work. **Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.**

Comment: put on a server but the error is just that ...
blank canvas.